# Proof that $L_X\omega=\iota_X(\mathrm{d}\omega+\omega\wedge\omega)$ if $\iota_X\omega=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, lie-derivative

Let $\nabla$ be a covariant derivative on a vector bundle $E\to M$ and suppose we are given a trivialization
$$E\to M\times V$$
where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. This trivialization defines a decomposition
$$\nabla=\mathrm{d}+\omega$$
(both $\mathrm d$ and $\omega$ depend on the chosen trivialization.) Now suppose that $\newcommand{\imult}{\mathbin{\lrcorner}}$
$$\iota_X\omega=0$$
for some vector field $X$ on $M$. In the book [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) (page $27$) it is claimed that this implies
$$L_X\omega=\iota_XF$$
where $F=\mathrm{d}\omega+\omega\wedge\omega$ is the curvature of $\nabla$. The following proof is given:
$$L_X\omega=[\iota_X,\omega]\omega=\iota_X(\mathrm{d}\omega+\omega\wedge\omega)$$
Unfortunately, this doesn't make sense to me: According to Cartan's formula, we have
$$L_X\omega=\iota_X\mathrm{d}\omega+\underbrace{\mathrm{d}\iota_X\omega}_{=0\text{ by assumption}}=\iota_X\mathrm{d}\omega.$$
So I get a different result ($\omega\wedge\omega$ is not necessarely zero, because endomorphisms do not necessarely commute)...

Comment: $\Large\stackrel{\bigodot\kern-0.975em\bullet\bigodot\kern-0.975em\bullet}{\Huge\smile}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$ \iota_X (\omega \wedge \omega)=[ \iota_X\omega, \omega] = 0$$

since $\iota_X\omega = 0$. The first equality can be checked directly: write $\omega = A_i dx^i$, where $A_i\in \operatorname{End}(E)$, and $X = X^k \partial_k$, $Y= Y^l\partial_l$,

\begin{split}
(\iota_X (\omega\wedge \omega)) (Y)= \omega \wedge \omega (X, Y) &=  A_i A_j dx^i \wedge dx^j (X^k \partial_k, Y^l \partial_l) \\
&= A_i A_j (X^i Y^j - X^jY^i) \\
&= \iota_X \omega \omega(Y) - \omega (Y) \iota_X \omega \\
&= [ \iota _X \omega, \omega] (Y)
\end{split}

Comment: Thank you! The book even uses the formula$$\iota_X(\alpha\wedge\beta)=(\iota_X\alpha)\wedge\beta+(-1)^{|\alpha|}\alpha\wedge(\iota_X\beta)$$to **define** the contraction, so I really should have noticed that.